# Why is my recycler view not displaying the correct data?

Tags: java, android

the issue I am having is that my recycler view is only showing the dummy data  (see)

```
fUser.add(new firebaseUser("Nate", "f"));
fUser.add(new firebaseUser("Nate", "f"));
fUser.add(new firebaseUser("Nate", "f"));
fUser.add(new firebaseUser("Nate", "f"));
```

and not any of the real data. You can see how I am querying firebase, and I have checked to make sure that It is getting data back. I cant seem to figure out why the recycler view is only showing the dummy data and not the combined data?

```
public class admin_viewuser extends AppCompatActivity {

    //ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
    ArrayList<firebaseUser> fUser;
    private FirebaseFirestore FireStore;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_viewuser);

        fUser = new ArrayList<>();
        FireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        query();
        fUser.add(new firebaseUser("Nate", "f"));
        fUser.add(new firebaseUser("Nate", "f"));
        fUser.add(new firebaseUser("Nate", "f"));
        fUser.add(new firebaseUser("Nate", "f"));





    }


    public void query() {
        FireStore
                .collection("groupss")
                .document("Lpux0m1ZmAHgiulBbvOZ") /* for testing would be users uid in real life */
                .collection("users")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> data = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                        for (DocumentSnapshot item : data) {
                            System.out.println(item.getData());
                            fUser.add(new firebaseUser(item));
                        }

                    }
                });
        System.out.println("FINISHED");
        addAdapter();


    }

    public void addAdapter() {
        System.out.println("CALLED NOW");
        RecyclerView rvContacts = findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);


        //contacts = Contact.createContactsList(20);
        ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(fUser);

        rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);

        rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}

class firebaseUser {
    private String uName;
    private String deleteID; //pos

    public firebaseUser(DocumentSnapshot data) {
        uName = data.get("user_name").toString();
        deleteID = data.get("deleteID").toString();
    }

    public firebaseUser(String name, String id) {
        uName = name;
        deleteID = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return uName;
    }

    public String getDeleteID() {
        return deleteID;
    }
}


class ContactsAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView nameTextView;
        public Button messageButton;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            messageButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_button);
        }
    }

    private List<firebaseUser> mContacts;

    public ContactsAdapter(List<firebaseUser> contacts) {
        mContacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_contact, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        firebaseUser contact = mContacts.get(position);
        System.out.println(contact);
        System.out.println("CALLED1");
        TextView textView = viewHolder.nameTextView;
        textView.setText(contact.getName());
        Button button = viewHolder.messageButton;
        button.setText("Kick User");


    }

    // Returns the total count of items in the list
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContacts.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed the working of an anonymous callback here . `onSucess` will get called when data is fetched but `addAdapter();` will get called immediately(Sequentially) after request. You should move `addAdapter()` in side `onSuccess()`. And  please follow the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/).

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is, you are trying to load the data before the fetch is complete. This is asynchronous. So if you put addAdapter() like this, it will work.

```
public void query() {
    FireStore
            .collection("groupss")
            .document("Lpux0m1ZmAHgiulBbvOZ") /* for testing would be users uid in real life */
            .collection("users")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> data = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot item : data) {
                        System.out.println(item.getData());
                        fUser.add(new firebaseUser(item));
                        addAdapter();
                    }

                }
            });
    System.out.println("FINISHED");



}
```